# Getting same HTML response from urlfetchapp for Youtube videos in google appscript

Tags: google-apps-script, youtube-api

I am trying to fetch the HTML code of different youtube video in Google appscript using urlfetchapp. Command is below -

var response1 = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JeDZwebDRkU");

But everytime I am running the command instead of getting the respective video's HTML, I am getting the home page HTML. Is there a way I can pull the source code which I am seeing from the actual video link?

Tried with multiple links but the HTML response was pretty much same except for 1 argument changing with the link I am using. The actual output expected is same to when I go to see the source code from any browser

Comment: Are you sure the response is the home page with that link? - [edit] the question and add the response of `UrlFetchApp.fetch`.